# How to run a *.o file in Android

Tags: android-ndk

I currently compiled  a set of source code in C in Linux and the output is a *.o file which is a object file. This supposedly does image compression. Now I want to use/test this in Android.

Is this possible? I have only tried NDK examples from the Android NDK developer side. Have not came across any reference on how this can be done.

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Answer (score 0):

You don't run object code files (*.o). You would need to turn it into an executable. To do this, assuming you are using GCC you would run `gcc file1.o file2.o -o executable` which would convert a two file program with file1.o and file2.o into an executable called executable.

Answer (score 0):

[Object files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (ending in .o) usually contain code that is incomplete. For example, if your program uses some library to print something on screen, to produce an executable, you must link your compiled code (the .o file) with the library, so that when the operating system loads the executable knows all the code that will be used. You do this linking with a [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (such as ld in Linux, or /system/bin/linker in Android). In your case, it's easier to let gcc call the linker for you, as Jalfor notes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. But you have to do some fair amount of work to see it running on Android.

1) If you are compiling on Linux, it means the object file or the final executable is being built for the x86 or AMD processor(Mostly). But mostly all the mobile devices have ARM processors running on their phones. So, though you have an executable you will not be able to execute it in ANdroid if it is not built for ARM Cpu. This is what android NDK does exactly.

2) So, we have to build the same code again for Android(ARM), for which we need a cross-compiler and the source code of the object files you are talking about.

3) If you have source code avilable, you can do 2 things again.

- To include it in JNI folder, build the shared library and then do the
  stuff of calling and all.
- Build the code into an executable(Note you    need to have main
  inside the code) using the android NDK and then push the executable    inside Android using
  adb.

Now finally you can login and then check the result. In case anything is not clear, please do let me know. I wont mind explaining. Thanks..

Comment: Hi happy2help, thanks for the info. Trying to find out how to use the android toolchain to compile. I have downloaded the android source code previously, thus under the prebuilt folder has the toolchains. Trying to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Inside Android NDK, you can file the tool chain. I dont have BDK readily available with me. But search the folder toolchain inside it. You will see executables like arm-eabi-gcc etc... I am not sure of exact name. But these are the executables you need to use. Where ever gcc is there, there you need to put arm-eabi-gcc.. Hope you got what am i trying to say...